# How can I increase resolution when impossible to set up nvidia driver?

Tags: 11.10, resolution, screen, nvidia

I was stuck at 1024x758 before creating an */etc/X11/xorg.conf* file as follows which works well to allow me to have a resolution of 1920x1200 with the vesa driver.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 24.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh 50.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       24
        Modes       "1920x1200"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

But now my display is kind of slow. I have an NVIDIA GeForce 8600GT but really cannot find how to set up the driver to work.

Are there any alternatives to VESA that would work faster?

Comment: [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11646502&postcount=11) mentions removal of `xorg.conf` & then reinstall nvidia drives. Can you try that?

Comment: I did this. It also works, but my screen resolution goes down to 1024x758 and the Nvidia driver is described as activated but not in use.
I'd rather have a slow display than a small resolution so I'll leave that xorg.conf file for now.

Comment: What system configuration (hardware + ubuntu version) do you use?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric on a Toshiba Qosmio G40.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. This is to help with the **Ask Ubuntu Clean Up**. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an xserver update solves your issue... just follow the steps here: [How to upgrade intel graphics package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124640/how-to-upgrade-intel-graphics-package/125197#125197)